# Is it possible to show the progress bar, but not the logger text in MoviePy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

Is it possible to remove the following text when running Moviepy?

```
MoviePy - Building video /ble/bla.mp4
MoviePy - writing audio in %s 
*Progress bar here*
Moviepy - Done !
MoviePy - video ready /ble/bla.mp4
```

and only have the progress bar loading?
I have my write_tofile() set up like this:

```
final.write_tofile("bla.mp4", logger='bar')
```

Comment: Did you mean `write_videofile` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import proglog
video.write_videofile(logger=proglog.TqdmProgressBarLogger(print_messages=False))
```

> print_messages
>
> If True, every `logger(message='something')` will print a message in the console / notebook

[Source](https://github.com/Edinburgh-Genome-Foundry/Proglog/blob/master/proglog/proglog.py#L286)